# Dynamic Transitions in Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-webflow-2

Does anybody know if it's possible to define dynamic transitions in a Spring Web Flow definition?

Example 1 - using a properties file:

```
<action-state id="createSubscription" >
    <evaluate expression="myvar" />
    <transition on="$[test.result.valid]" to="subscribeUser-successResponse" />
    <transition                               to="subscribeUser-exceptionResponse" />
</action-state>
```

Example 2 - using the value of the variable itself:

```
<action-state id="createSubscription" >
    <evaluate expression="myvar" />
    <transition to="$[myvar]" />
</action-state>
```

It's not mandatory, but could help to design more generic flows.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do definitely do for transition "to".
Suppose flow xml has some action and view state as:

```
    <action-state id="createSubscription">
        <evaluate expression="myAction.prepareNextState(flowScope.formBean)"/>
        <transition to="${flowScope.formBean.displayNextState}">
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="someView" view="someView" model="formBean">
        ...
    </view-state>
```

and myAction class with prepareNextState method is as:

```
    public class MyAction implements Serializable{
        ....
        public void prepareNextState(FormBean formBean){
            //displayNextState is a String field in FormBean                
            formBean.setDisplayNextState("someView");
        }
        ....
    }
```

This way we can define generic transitions for transition "to".

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it looks very good. I marked the answer as the correct one expecting it works. Thank you.

Comment: I did implement a similar one though through view state with multiple buttons where the transition "to" have to be different for different buttons where displayNextState will be the button clicked by user ;)

Comment: Only thing is, we need to make sure that displayNextState is not null when that transition is invoked.

Comment: Are you sure it works? Is there any specific configuration of Web Flow necessary? I tried, and it fails, no variable is accepted. Furthermore, this is the only place where dynamic transition is mentioned. It would be nice to use it though.